# Onclick change background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Jquery code:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
      if($(this).css("background-color")=="#FFFFFF") 
         $(this).css("background-color","blue");
     else
         if($(this).css("background-color")=="blue")
              $(this).css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
    });
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    click me!
</div>
```

Can you explain to me why it does not work??

Thank you very much

http://jsfiddle.net/m73faf4g/

Comment: `$(this).css("background-color") == rgb(255,255,255)` - that's why.

Comment: `alert($(this).css("background-color"));` And see if its really `ffffff`

Comment: @u_mulder alert is not a debuging tool :)

Comment: lol @WilfredoP so true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also forgot to include *JQuery* in your fiddle

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m73faf4g/13/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function() {
       if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
          $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
       else
          if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)')
              $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    });
});
```

---

### Edit

Alternative Way, if you wish :

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('blue');
    });
});
```

### [Alternative Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr9fvuvs/1/)

Comment: lol beat me to it. I was clicking his fiddle, then noticed $ is undefined

Answer (score 1):

use it like this:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    if($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") 
        $(this).css("background-color","blue");
    else
        if($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(0, 0, 255)")
            $(this).css("background-color","#FFFFFF");
});
```

the reason is that `css()` function returns `rgb` formatted color which won't work with your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Create a toggle function that doesn't rely on the color, as the returned style can be inconsistent in different browsers depending on wether they support rgb/rgba/hsl etc.

```
$("#test").on('click', function() {

    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $(this).css('background-color', flag ? '#fff' : 'blue');

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m73faf4g/8/)